# My transaction is 2 blocks earlier than the competitor, but mine is failed and his successful. Why?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethers.js, opensea

this's my transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5a35ccae0ecee4b645bd7bf26c15efef7e82d6b2e170627c85815ffbc49c8cf0
this's his transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1107760fa3b1250f1dc889de4878165070f2b7da9b822f835686fef02147b116

we both were buying the same item on opensea: https://opensea.io/assets/ethereum/0x658bdf5cba855e04724589a61c3e4b1856b69a5b/4170

I was sending trx to opensea Contract, and he to his own contract.

my trx is mined at 15444017, his at 15444019. but his is successful. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction [reverts](https://etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x5a35ccae0ecee4b645bd7bf26c15efef7e82d6b2e170627c85815ffbc49c8cf0&type=parity) with the following error

```
0x6f7eac26
```

From the 4bytes.directory that value corresponds to `InvalidTime()`. It is likely the offer wasn't within the time allowed.

Comment: a new skill get!